# Plone Selection Widget

Tags: jquery, plone

I need a selection widget to change a string widget.  For example, when an item is selected in the selection widget, the background in the text widget changes color. I can get this to work when a first text widget is changed to get the background color to change in a second text widget but not using a selection widget.  This is on Plone 4.1.  Here is the code:

```
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq("input[name= textwidget]").ready(function(){
        jq("input[name= textwidget]").css("background-color","red");
    });
    jq("input[name= selectionwidget]").change(function(){
        jq("input[name= textwidget]").css("background-color","green");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because a selection widget is a `<select>` tag and not an `<input>` tag.
You should try this:

```
jq(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    jq("select[name= selectionwidget]").change(function(){
        jq("input[name= textwidget]").css("background-color","green");
     });
});
```

Comment: You should "accept" Giacomo's answer so that the question is closed and he gets his whuffie points. :-)